# Bash script to rename some files with a suffix

Tags: bash, file-rename

I have a folder and I want to add a suffix behind the filename. I know for one file this code works... but how can I change all files once:

```
mv file1 file1.sh
```

Thanks :D

Comment: How are the files named? all of them start with `file`?

Comment: check for `for loop` in bash. something like this could be a start `for file in *;do mv $file $file.sh ;done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example to get you going:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=$(find /path/to/folder -type f)
for file in $files
do
mv $file $file.sh
done
```

Save it in a `file` , and then `bash <filename>`